# Positioning of vertical line in tabular environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

How can I adjust `\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.15\textwidth}|p{13cm}@{}}` to adjust the vertical position of `|`?

`|` is not aligned with the text that follows.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Sean

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb, marvosym, fontspec, titlesec, xunicode, xltxtra, parskip, phonenumbers, geometry, color, graphicx, wrapfig, hyperref, arydshln}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}

\section*{Title} \vspace{.7em}

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.15\textwidth}|p{13cm}@{}}

9/2018 --- 12/2018 & Hi \\ \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

9/2011 --- 7/2017 & Hi \\ \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

9/2005 --- 7/2011 & HI \\ \multicolumn{2}{c}{}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example -- test document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` -- that replicates the problem you wish to fix. The snippet `\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.15\textwidth}|p{13cm}@{}}` does not suffice.

Comment: Please prepare a a complete and compilable MWE that allows others to reproduce the output and add this example document to your question.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to acheive...

Comment: A sketch or a description of the expected output would also be really useful here. A MWE closer to the actual documen could also be useful here. The screenshot you show contains three lines of text in the right column, the MWE ou posted just contains a single word. and with the MWE you provided so far, I'm unable to recreate an output close to the one you show.

Comment: Probably you get the expected output if you add `\\ `after the last `\multicolumn{2}{c}{}` in your table. Alternatively, you could just remove this line entirely as it does  not seem to serve any purpose here, anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the attached result.
I just put the \multicolumn once in the beginning, but I extended the textwidth to 0.17, the minimum you need to have all data in one single row. The threefold stripe is ugly and unusual in typesetting. I substituted it by a double.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb, marvosym, fontspec, titlesec, xunicode, xltxtra, parskip,     phonenumbers, geometry, color, graphicx, wrapfig, hyperref, arydshln}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}

\section*{Title} \vspace{.7em}%

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.17\textwidth}|p{13cm}@{}}%
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
9/2018 -- 12/2018 & Hi \\

9/2011 -- 7/2017 & Hi \\% \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\

9/2005 -- 7/2011 & HI \\% \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Comment: This and the solution posed by @leandriis in the comments, has resolved the issue. Thanks.